# django use of quotes in url template tag

Tags: django

In myusers.urls I have set app_name = 'users' and name='users' in the urlpatterns.

Why are quotes needed around users:users in the following:

```
<a href="{% url 'users:users' %}">/users</a>
```

is that a shortcut? Do the quotes tell django to resolve the address? Would the following work?

```
<a href="{% url myusers.views.users %}">/users</a>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('users/', views.users, name='users'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from myusers.models import *

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'myusers/index.html')

def users(request):
    users = AllUser.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'myusers/users.html', {'users':users})
```

Comment: Please show the exactly code with `app_name = users`…

Comment: question updated.

Comment: That's `app_name = 'users'`, with quotes…

Comment: ok, but that doesn't answer the question

Comment: `url myusers.views.users` would try to refer to a variable `myusers` in your template context, which probably doesn't exist. In the end `url` expects a string. Whether this string comes from a variable or not doesn't matter. So yes, `url myusers.views.users` *would* work if it resolved to a string…

Comment: so in this example could I just use <a href="{% url 'users' %}">/users</a> as long as I don't have other apps with name='users' in their urls.py file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unquoted arguments are [template variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#variables), not python variables, not module references, but only names with values provided to the template. This is the "context" passed to templates from views, where the key is the variable name. It can also be variables inside [for loops](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for) and [with](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#with) constructs.

Quoted arguments are strings.

The [URL tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url) uses its string arguments to resolve urls, by using Django's [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) and that's it. The string "users:users", refers to the [URL namespace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) "users" and the view with name "users".

Comment: so in this example could I just use <a href="{% url 'users' %}">/users</a> as long as I don't have other apps with name='users' in their urls.py file?

Comment: To keep the terminology correct: yes, you can try to reverse only "URL names", without the use of a "Namespace".